# How to implement secure network message passing using Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, network-programming

I'm interested in having clients, on iOS/OS X platforms using Cocoa, having secure transaction with a dedicated server.  I'm looking for the easiest and most 'proper' use of the fancy highly abstracted APIs that Apple has developed.  An example of what I'm talking about with those "fancy" APIs is that https is implemented "for free" and could suit my purposes - except that I don't know how to implement the corresponding server portion of that?

The network messages basically need to be a secure session where a client can create an account, or log in with that account, can send a request to the server, and receive a response from the server.  The traffic is low volume, latency is OK, most important thing is to implement confidentiality and to make my software effort as short as possible.

The server will be on FreeBSD and will either run Cocoa via Cocotron or can use some other  technology you mention that would make development faster.  The computation being done on the server is minimal, requires db intfc, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the client side, `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLConection` all support HTTPS mode. You could also try third party libraries such as [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).

On the server side, I'm not sure what you mean by "The server will be on FreeBSD and will either run Cocoa via Cocotron". Are you saying that your server will be written in Objective-C and using Cocoa API? I'm not really sure why you want to do something like that. If the code on server is minimal, why not use the Apache server combined with `mod_ssl` and perhaps PHP to get it done? PHP is excellent for quick and dirty server. You can also use django / rails and other established frameworks (all of which support HTTPS) if those suit your need better.

Comment: This. Unless you're trying to do peer-to-peer connections between clients (a different challenge all together) it makes no sense to write an HTTP server in Cocoa; You could do it, but why would you?  If you wanted to write your server-side application code with Cocoa/Obj-C, I would still recommend using a pre-existing HTTP server (like apache) and developing your app-logic as a plug-in for that server, or as an external CGI application.

Comment: Yeah, this is even *more* important since you cite security as a design goal. Don't re-invent this wheel.

Comment: @ipmcc how could I use that application logic (assume it's a binary) as a plug-in for apache?